# Redux Action not returning JSON?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm struggling to figure out why my redux action is not returning the JSON from the GET request, even though when I submit the GET request in Postman, I can access the information?

The error I have returning is: Profile Not Found. Yet, like I said when I do the Postman request, it's working fine.

This Redux Action doesn't work:

```
// Get profile by id for admins
export const getUserProfile = (id) => dispatch => {
   dispatch(setProfileLoading());
    axios.get(`/admin/profile/${id}`)
      .then(res => 
          dispatch({
              type: GET_PROFILE,
              payload: res.data
          })    
      )
      .catch(err => 
          dispatch({
              type: GET_ERRORS,
          payload: err.response.data
      })   
  );
}
```

Here is the Admin route which works in Postman and is returning the JSON?

```
router.get('/admin/profile/:id', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
    session: false
}), (req, res) => {

const errors = {};

User.findOne({
        user: req.user.id
    })
    .then(user => { 
        if (req.user.role === 'admin') {
            Profile.findById(req.params.id)
                .then(profile => {
                    res.json(profile);
                })
                .catch(err => res.status(404).json({
                    profilenotfound: 'Profile not found'
                }));
        } else {
            res.json({unauthorized: 'User is unauthorized to view this area'})
        }
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json(err));
```

});

Here is the reducer:

```
import { GET_PROFILE, PROFILE_LOADING, CLEAR_CURRENT_PROFILE, GET_PROFILES } 
from '../actions/types';



const initialState = {
    profile: null,
    profiles: null,
    loading: false
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case PROFILE_LOADING: 
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        case GET_PROFILE:
            return {
                ...state,
                profile: action.payload,
                loading: false
            }
        case GET_PROFILES: 
            return {
                ...state,
                profiles: action.payload,
                loading: false
            }
        case CLEAR_CURRENT_PROFILE: 
            return {
                ...state,
                profile: null
            }
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem most likely is in your `reducer`.Could you post the code for it?

Comment: Edited the post to include the reducer. It's the same reducer I use for a different component. The only thing I swapped out on the Admin component versus the working component is the getUserProfile action. I didn't change any of the reducers. Also, thanks for helping. I've been at a loss for an hour lol

Comment: Hmm. Everything looks ok. You're not receiving the `error` neither?

Comment: Can you check if the id you are passing through the component is actually the correct one by doing a `console.log(id)` inside the action?

Comment: @Dupocas the error I'm receiving is just "cannot find profile" which I set elsewhere if there was an error retrieving the info.

Comment: @RohitKashyap I put the console.log(id) underneath the dispatch, and it just returned undefined. Am I supposed to change the id to be something like: req.params.id   instead of just id?

Comment: Here you go, that's what's wrong.

Comment: You need to pass an id to the action in the component where you are calling it from, the function expects an id and you are not passing one.

Comment: @RohitKashyap Ok that makes sense. Do I delcare that in the componentDidMount? Like so:     componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getUserProfile(id);
    }

Comment: Yes, whatever the id is you need to pass it.

Comment: @RohitKashyap  I'm still getting undefined when I just pass in (id). How do I go about passing in the req.param.id? Sorry I'm so unfamiliar with this.

Comment: You can't just pass id variable, the id needs to be the actual profile id of the user, that's how the server will respond with the correct information.

Comment: Post the code for your component. The problem is definitely there. This `id` is supposed to get from where?

Comment: Yeah I realized I wasn't passing in the right thing in my App.js. I was playing around with it earlier and was passing in /admin/profile/:user_id to the Component... and then in the route it was: /:id    (So basically I'm dumb and wasted 2 hours for nothing lol)

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned in the comments the problem is that you are not passing the id, you need to pass the id when you call your Redux action in your component for example if you call your getUserProfile method it should be something like that:

```
componentDidMount() { 
    const {getUserProfile} = this.props; // This is destructuring for better readability
    // Here you need to pass your id for example 1234 or get it from params or from wherever you want...
    getUserProfile(1234); 
}
```

Comment: Yeah I realized I wasn't passing in the right thing in my App.js. I was playing around with it earlier and was passing in /admin/profile/:user_id to the Component... and then in the route it was: /:id    (So basically I'm dumb and wasted 2 hours for nothing lol)

Comment: Haha it happens, at least we found the issue :D